# file path from list won't load python

Tags: python

I can load the image if i hard code the path but when i try to pick up the string from the list i keep getting an error message. not sure what am i doing wrong.

```
#for i in range(0,len(training_YFT)):
    #print(training_YFT[i])
#image = Image.open("/media/rafael/Data1/train/YFT/img_00004.jpg")
image = Image.open(training_YFT[0])
#image = Image.open(training_YFT[i]).convert("L")
arr = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(arr,  cmap='gray')
plt.pause(0.01)
plt.show()
```

I pasted below the error message i am getting. n

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2283, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fishy.py", line 95, in <module>
    image = Image.open(training_YFT[0])
  File "/home/rafael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2285, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: very strange. can you perform a `dir(training_YFT[0])` and show us the results?

Comment: thanks found the problem first element of my list is empty.

Comment: I tested it with an empty string and I had the "no such file or directory" message as expected. Strange (I believe you since the messages states that a `str` object has been passed, but that should have tried to open the file, not to seek on it)

Answer (score -1):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafael/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2283, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

So the first error is that the object you're trying to call is the `file` object, but the variable is actually a string object.

And the `str` object does not have a function called seek

So moving on to the list problem.

Try printing out of the list, ensuring that it isn't a `str`

`['path1', 'path2']`

if it is indeed a list, it should return to you `path1`

if it is a string, it will return `p`, which is not what you want

Next, it looks like the class `Image` wants a file object, and you're passing it a string. Though it's strange you passed it a string before and it seemed to work. My suggestion is try `Image.open(open(variable))`

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

I've never played with the PIL package, but, the best thing you can do is print out your variables before and after the functions, ensure they are the variables you'd like to pass

```
print(training_YFT)
if not type(training_YFT) == list: print('training_YFT IS NOT A LIST, you\'re giving the function '+training_YET[0]+'!')
image = Image.open(training_YFT[0])
print(image)
arr = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(arr,  cmap='gray')
plt.pause(0.01)
plt.show()
```

Another suggestion, is ensuring the file path's existence. You can do this by importing os.path isfile. E.g `from os.path import isfile`

There's no way to tell you exactly what's wrong with your code since there isn't enough information to exactly determine without all the source code. But I hope this helped, and gave you ideas to try when things aren't working.

Comment: If you look at the PIL docs, they seem to show that passing a string OR a file is OK.